# Analyzing queries in the client side of Elasticsearch but not on the server

Tags: java, search, lucene, elasticsearch, query-parser

We are migrating our Lucene based search codebase to Elasticsearch. The major problem we encountered is how we should migrate our `QueryParser`s.

In our old solution, the QueryParsers take in a human input query string, and transform that to Lucene's `Query` object, which is then fed into Lucene's IndexSearcher. However, in Elasticsearch we don't directly interact with IndexSearcher, instead we can only build the queries in the client side using [Query DSL](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html) and send the JSON to Elasticsearch server. Elasticsearch server then (possibly) rewrites/analyses the JSON query to build a Lucene query.

To make use of our existing and sophisticated logic in QueryParsers, we decided that we can stick to our old approach by:

1. Explicitly tell Elasticsearch to **NOT analyze** any query in the search time.
2. Do **ALL** the query related analysis (tokenizing, synonym, etc) in the Java client.
3. Believe that Elasticsearch's Query DSL is kind of a one-to-one mapping to Lucene's `Query`

Don't worry about the scoring process, we are writing our scorer scripts as a Elasticsearch plugin.

The questions are:

1. Is this approach feasible?
2. What are the potential problems in doing so?
3. What is the best practice?

Thanks in advance!